# Incorrect answer time on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, timestamps

[image: This picture shows that Hesky Fisher answered this question on 2009-11-24]

[image: This picture shows that Hesky Fisher entered Stack Overflow at 2012]

How can a person answer a question without entering the community? I don't understand. Maybe the time in picture doesn't mean the answering time.

Comment: Merged profile probably. Or something similar - 99% chance this is just a weird case in the system and this isn't a bug.

Comment: I have also found some similar situations that I mentioned in this question in  Stack exchange data dump. And I now doubt whether the two fields in StackOverflow are accurate according to these abnormal situations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user's account was (probably) deleted at one point. "Probably" because records going that far back are not always consistent or available, so I'm guessing on that part.

The post ownership was reassigned to the new profile a couple years ago. We don't do this often as profile deletion is serious and shouldn't be taken lightly, and  verifying post ownership after deletions can be tricky. Nevertheless, that's the explanation here.

Comment: Oh, I know. Thank you very much

Comment: So interesting to find a discussion about me. 

It's true that my account was deleted at some point. It's possible that the account was deleted because I accidentally made a second account having forgotten about the first one.

But I was pretty fond of this answer so when I saw it was no longer attributed to me I opened a ticket and it was fixed.